# Docker out of memory exception

Tags: docker, docker-compose, out-of-memory, sylius

So I currently tried to add this plugin: https://github.com/FriendsOfSylius/SyliusImportExportPlugin to my sylius project, which runs over docker. But I got an out of memory exception all the time.

I tried: `docker-compose exec php composer require friendsofsylius/sylius-import-export-plugin --dev`

I got: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223`

After some time I tried some others* too and got the same error again so I don't think it is my memory limit, also due to the fact that this is a memory size over 2GB. Has anyone an idea why my memory size exhaust all the time?

I am using an MacOS system with mojave 10.14.5.

*For example:

`docker-compose exec php composer update --profile --ignore-platform-reqs --dry-run`

`docker-compose exec php composer require rubenrua/symfony-clean-tags-composer-plugin`

Comment: Docker for Mac secretly runs a VM with a memory limit.  Look in (Whale), Preferences, “Advanced” tab.

Comment: I already increased the Memory to 10GiB there, but thanks for answering.

Comment: It looks like you forgot an infinite loop somewhere, could it be? For example when entity getter call itself with no exit condition